# Using text file in SQLite

Tags: android, android-emulator, sqlite

I am dealing with ECG signal processing using Android phone.  I am getting the filtered ECG signal after the series of operations as my final output, and it is saved in text file in particular location.  The text file contains the values of voltages in a single column, containing 30000 samples.  This is done for number of patients.

Now I have to use these text files in my database with particular patients, as a entry in their row.
I am using SQLite database.
How can it be done?
please help me with this.

Comment: this is your answer http://notes.theorbis.net/2010/02/batch-insert-to-sqlite-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Read the file and save it as blob in sqlite, but if data is too large, you will have problems with size. Another way would b to keep the files in sdcard with some id as filename, you could save these ids in db which you can refer.

Answer (score 0):

OK basically what you need to do is:

1. bulkinsert your data. 
   here is the link on how to do it:
   http://notes.theorbis.net/2010/02/batch-insert-to-sqlite-on-android.html
2. if you need to populate your second table with this data then

`update yourtable set blah=(select field from yourfreshlypopulatedtable)`